# How should I list presentations given at workshops on my CV?

Tags: cv, presentation, workshop

I'm in a humanities field, and I'm wondering if presentations given at small workshops should be listed in a separate section of my CV, for instance between "Invited Talks" and "Conferences".

Small workshops differ in several ways from conferences in my field: they are normally more competitive, participation for speakers is often fully funded, and they are usually attended by a broader audience (whereas at conferences you're speaking to other conference participants). I would consider acceptance at this type of workshop more prestigious than a conference presentation but less prestigious than an invited talk.

Thoughts on giving these workshops their own section? If not their own section, should I give them a sub-header under "Conferences"?

Answer (score 1):

Any position that builds your career or profession has a rightful place on your CV. It sounds like your workshop leading experience has done that, so I would vote to put it on. To be clear, I'm assuming that by "presentations in workshops" you mean that you led a workshop where participants worked through something (since "workshops" are typically not lectures my field--I could be mistaken about your field), which I'll refer to as "workshops facilitated"

The question of where to categorize it is more complex I think, and it depends on the nature of the workshops. I think there are three main options:

**1. "Workshops facilitated" sub-heading under a "Conferences" or "Presentations" Category**

If you think the skills you developed and displayed in facilitating the workshops is similar to the skills developed and displayed in participating in conferences, **and** your workshops were about research of a caliber you would present at a conference.

**2. "Workshops facilitated" sub-heading under a "Teaching Experience" category**

If the workshops you facilitated were more focused on general topics than your own independent research.

**3. "Workshops facilitated" as its own category**

If the workshops you've facilitated do not fall neatly into one of the two categories above. If the workshops you've facilitated are very distinct from either of these options, or if you've facilitated a mixture of workshops, I think it's reasonable to put them in their own category. You could even have sub-headings of "Research-focused workshops", "Introductory workshops" or "pedagogical workshops", etc.

Comment: The OP hasn't said he "facilitated" workshops, just that he gave presentations in them. So a heading "Workshops" would suffice.

Comment: @Sverre oh good catch -- however for me "Workshops" aren't really something you present at: you facilitate participants working through something, which is what I assume OP meant. This is what I meant. I'll edit to be clearer.

Comment: Good point. Let me clarify. In my field, "workshop" refers to one of two things: 1) a half-day session at a conference where several people present papers on the same topic; 2) a half-day to multi-day independent and often interdisciplinary event, more competitive than your typical conference, sometimes by invitation only, where several people present papers on the same topic (sometimes also called a "symposium"). The fact that the word "workshop" is used for both is a complicating factor.

Comment: I do have "Workshops organized" as a subheader under "Conference activity" on my CV for workshops type 1. My challenge with type 2 is they seem, qualitatively, to fall between conferences and invited talks on the measures of selectivity and funding. Should those considerations matter for the organization of the CV? Or should I just lump them under "Conference activity" because the research is a similar caliber to what one would present at a conference?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the field. In my field, workshops are for presentations. And that seems to be the case for the OP as well.